# Phonegap: initiate download on iOS

Tags: ios, file, cordova, download

Within my app I'm making a zip file (using JSZip) which I need to download (not write to the file system, but actually initiate a download) to the iOS device where the app is hosted. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might get the effect you're looking for with the [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) plugin. It should try to open the file with the built-in browser and then it would be up to the user to handle it.

`window.open('http://location.to/the.zip', '_system');`